# JMeter JMX file compatibility

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Not able to open Test plan on Jmeter version v3.1 which has been created on JMeter version v2.12 r1636949 . Please provide if there is any solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at *jmeter.log* file, it usually contains enough troubleshooting information so you will be able to figure out the cause of the problem.

I can see 3 reasons for this behavior:

1. You are using Test Element(s) which was(were) deprecated. If this is the case - check our [Incompatible Changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html#Incompatible%20changes) section of JMeter release notes to learn what component(s) should be used instead
2. You are using [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which were installed on JMeter 2.12 and JMeter 3.1 instance does not have these plugins. In that case use [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) to re-install the missing plugins
3. You are using 3-rd party libraries in [JUnit](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) or Beanshell code. In that case copy them from JMeter 2.12 somewhere into [Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) of JMeter 3.1